# Azure function with Isolation .net6.0 function not adding teams webhook

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions, asp.net-core-webapi

[image]
Add Webhook c# code which works in IN PROCESS .net core 6.0 but not works in ISOLATED PROCESS azure functions

```
var sub = new Microsoft.Graph.Subscription
{
    ChangeType = "created",
    NotificationUrl = _options.WebhookNoticationUrl,
    Resource = "communications/callRecords",
    ExpirationDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(Convert.ToInt32(_options.WebhookExpirationTime)), // add hours
    ClientState = _options.ClientState
};

    var newSubscription = await graphServiceClient
        .Subscriptions
        .Request()

        .AddAsync(sub);`
```

Getting Error while adding webhook. Error message Subscription validation request failed. Response must exactly match

Add Webhook c# code which works in IN PROCESS .net core 6.0 but not works in ISOLATED PROCESS azure functions

Answer (score 0):

I have used the code below to invoke `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions` for resource `communications/callRecords`. In order to access this resource, you need to grant **CallRecords.Read.All** permission to the registered App as per the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/callrecords-cloudcommunications-list-callrecords?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#permissions).

I have created a .NET8 HTTP triggered isolated function.

**Function code**-

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace _77999133
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            var validationToken = req.Query["validationToken"];
            _logger.LogInformation(validationToken);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(validationToken))
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("validationToken: " + validationToken);
                return new ContentResult { Content = validationToken, ContentType = "text/plain" };
            }

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GraphNotification>(requestBody);

            return new OkResult();
        }

        public class GraphNotification
        {
            public List<ChangeNotification> value { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

I deployed my code to function app and used it in the  payload.

```json
{
"changeType": "created",
"notificationUrl": "https://{functionApp_name}.azurewebsites.net/api/Function1",
"resource": "communications/callRecords",
"expirationDateTime": "2024-02-15T11:00:00.0000000Z",
"clientState": "SecretClientState"
}
```

**Postman**-

Add the Bearer token for Authorization.

[image]